# Save files to device only my application can see

Tags: android, file, save

I need to save files to local folder in my device.

This folder should be encrypted or shouldn't be seen.

Is it possible to do something like that in Android?

I know I can use shared preference or SQLite DB, but I need to save files not simple values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can save files to the internal storage of the device, which will be private to your application. Remember this storage is limited on most devices, and thats why the SD Card is the best place to store files.

[Internal Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)

You could hash the files on the SD Card though, and only your application could access them because it has the key used to hash the files.

Comment: How can I hash the files on my SD Card? can you expand little more? In addition, are these files can't be seen from Files Explorer application like ES File Explorer?

Comment: if you don't have root permission, ES File explorer can't see any internal storage. If you have root permission, you can access wherever the file located. If you want to avoid it, you can encrypt the file content